# If $f(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow c$, what can we say about the convergence of $\sqrt{f(x)\,}$?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

There is a standard problem that I have been going through:

Let $f(x)\rightarrow L$ as $x\rightarrow a$ for some $L>0$. Prove that $\sqrt{f(x)\,}\rightarrow \sqrt{L\,}$ as $x\rightarrow c$.

I have done this and am more than happy with my answer, but I wondered about the strict inequality on $L$: can this be changed to a weak one?

What I have so far is:

Since $f(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow c$ then there must exist $\delta>0$ such that for any $\epsilon>0$:

$$|x-c|\,\leq\,\delta \quad\Longrightarrow\quad 0\,\leq\,|f(x)|\,\leq\,\ \epsilon^{2} \quad\Longrightarrow\quad \sqrt{|f(x)|\,} \,\leq\, \epsilon.$$

But I don't know how to remove the $|\cdot|$ from around $f(x)$ under the square root (notice I am not restricting $f$ to be a positive function). Any help/thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no guarantee that $\sqrt{f(x)}$ is even defined in a neighborhood of $c$. Consider for instance $f(x)=x\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ and $c=0$.

Comment: Point well taken; but with $L>0$, this is sufficient to have $\sqrt{f(x)\,}$ defined in such a neighbourhood right? Otherwise that's my first part invalidated also!

Comment: Yes: if $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L>0$ then $f(x)>\frac{L}{2}>0$ for all $x$ close enough to $c$ (except possibly $x=c$).

Comment: Excellent - thanks for the pointers.